# How to reset your database in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to wipe out all the data in the rows in the tables that I have, how do i do it?.. I want to completely delete them. I have 4 tables, and i prefer  to delete/ reset them altogether..

``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://blogs.officezealot.com/mauro/archive/2006/03/12/9402.aspx) may help you. It uses the built in sp_MSForEachTable to check/remove constraints and then truncate the data

Comment: Thats what i did... i removed all of the relationships and used the delete command

Answer (score 0):

SQL Table?
try `truncate table [tablename]` - this should delete and reset ids

Comment: The TRUNCATE TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported. --It says it cant truncate the Users table cause it has foreign keys. what do i do now.. i want to delete the rows..while leaving the columns

Comment: DELETE FROM Topics // i used that and i got the same problem\

Answer (score 0):

Tim's solution is good, but just make sure that you are aware of any dependencies in your table.
start by deleting the farthest child table in the relation, and go up one level till you reach to a table with only foreign keys to other tables.

and it's always better to keep it as a SQL script that you may run whenever you need to do the reset.

Comment: I went and did what u told me.. i get the same error...it says that the table is referenced by a Foreign key

Comment: yes I know, most of the time your tables will have many relations according to the reqirments of your Database.
Start by deleting data from the table that it's primary key is not in a relation with another table as a foreign key, then it will be deleted successfully.
then go up one level, and keep doing so till you end up deleting all the data from all the tables.

my answer still applicable, give it a try and let me know the results.